# Delegation not found at parent...?

Tags: domain-name-system

I hope someone can help me with this.

If I run the following test -

```
http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=www.empleosmadrid.es
```

I get the following error:

> Delegation not found at parent. No delegation could be found at the parent, making your zone unreachable from the Internet.

I have tried googling the error but I am not finding much.

Does anyone know what the error means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 20):

Try http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=www.empleosmadrid.es or http://www.intodns.com/empleosmadrid.es instead.

The error you were given means that the nameservers for `empleosmadrid.es` have not delegated the subdomain of `www.empleosmadrid.es` to a different set of nameservers.

The confusion I think you are having here is that the check you are performing is for a *zone* and not for a *record*.  The `www.empleosmadrid.es` *record* is working fine.  The `empleosmadrid.es` *zone* is working fine.  The `www.empleosmadrid.es` *zone* doesn't exist, so you get an error message.

Of course, let me know if you *are* actually trying to delegate the `www` subdomain to a different set of nameservers, because if you are then you have a different problem.

If all you want to do is check that a record exists and returns the correct value, a simple `dig www.empleosmadrid.es` or `nslookup www.empleosmadrid.es` is enough for that.  The IntoDNS check above includes a lookup for `www`.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide a solution...

Comment: The problem was that he was asking the wrong question. The solution I provided was two different ways to ask the right question.