# Pingdom error: "No delegation could be found at the parent" when analyzing subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, a-record

I have a subdomain dramarsarin.crimsonandcyan.com which i wanted to point to another server. I added an A record in the zone file for crimsonandcyan.com with the host 'dramarsarin' and pointed it to the server's ip address.

Now when i do a dns check on pingdom.com for my subdomain, i get this:

```
No delegation could be found at the parent, making your zone unreachable from the Internet.
```

How can i fix this? I do see that sometimes it takes too long to resolve the subdomain. That is why i think the analysis of pingdom.com is pretty valid.

Comment: Did you update NS record for this domain at any point? `dig NS crimsonandcyan.com` returns an empty response sometimes, this is likely the reason why you are getting this error from pingdom.com as well.

Comment: Yes i did, but not recently. But i've checked that now they are set correctly.

Comment: Disregarding the Pingdom error which looks to be a red herring, can you include `dig` output which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I tried the dig command, but i think everything works fine. Can i ignore the pingdom error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delegation not found at parent...?](https://serverfault.com/questions/460653/delegation-not-found-at-parent)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Pingdom DNS check tool](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/) does not clearly state this but from its behavior it's clear that it expects the name of a zone, not just any domain name.

Ie, whatever you enter it expects that it should be a zone of its own (with delegation in place), which will not be the case in your example.

Comment: Right. So do i actually need to make a zonefile separately for the subdomain?

Comment: @KanishkDudeja No. It's just that the pingdom check is not suitable for this purpose.